# Trying to add a component to smart admin

Tags: angular, smartadmin

I'm working on an already working website which was built using Smart Admin template.

I'm trying to add a component to the dashboard as a first step.

Here are the commands and steps I followed:

-Command line:

```
ng g module test --routing
cd test
ng g component test --flat
```

-Added in file app.routing.ts:

```
{path: 'test',loadChildren:'app/test/test.module#TestModule'}
```

-Added in file test-routing.module.ts:

```
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
  path:'',
  component:TestComponent
  }
];
```

-Added in file test-routing.module.ts

```
import { SmartadminModule } from '../shared/smartadmin.module';
```

and

```
SmartadminModule inside imports:[]
```

The test.component.html only contains:

```
<p>
  test works!
</p>
```

When i call the page I'm getting the dashboard,header, footer...
However in other modules in the project, the dashboard ... are included explicitly by adding :

```
<sa-header></sa-header>
<sa-navigation></sa-navigation>
<div id="main" role="main">
  <sa-ribbon></sa-ribbon>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<sa-footer></sa-footer>
<sa-shortcut></sa-shortcut>
```

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Just to check, your issue is, that the routing does not navigate to your `test` component?

Comment: No my issue is that, i dont want the dashboard and header to show unless I add them to test.component using
 <sa-header></sa-header>
<sa-navigation></sa-navigation>

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the snippet with layout you provided is from `app.component.html`. So you can change it a bit to look like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<sa-footer></sa-footer>
<sa-shortcut></sa-shortcut>
```

And then have a `test.component.ts` look like this

```
<sa-header></sa-header>
<sa-navigation></sa-navigation>
<div id="main" role="main">
  <sa-ribbon></sa-ribbon>
  <!-- Other components or HTML code -->
</div>
```

What I can't tell is how will this change affect other routes and if it's a desired behavior.

Might be better to keep the HTML as is and do a minor change in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

showHeaderAndNavigation: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe(event => {
    this.showHeaderAndNavigation = event.url === '/test';
    //console.log(this.showHeaderAndNavigation);
  });
}
```

And then you can change your `app.component.html`

```
<sa-header *ngIf="showHeaderAndNavigation"></sa-header>
<sa-navigation *ngif="showHeaderAndNavigation"></sa-navigation>
<div id="main" role="main">
  <sa-ribbon></sa-ribbon>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<sa-footer></sa-footer>
<sa-shortcut></sa-shortcut>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
There is no app.component.html in the project.

The snippet I provided is from another file called payment-services.component.html and when i remove the snippet from this file, the dashboard, header and footer disappear.

I want the new module i'm adding (Test) to act the same way.

Comment: Could you please provide stackblitz? I'm bit confused of what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you dallows for your concern.
My project is not on stackblitz. Can I provide you team viewer access in a way so you can check what i mean ?

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repo? It might be easier as I can't allow much time for a "video call"